# Vaex convert csv to feather instead of hdf5

Tags: dataframe, vaex

Does vaex provide a way to convert `.csv` files to `.feather` format? I have looked through documentation and examples and it appears to only allow conversion to `.hdf5` format. I see that the dataframe has a `.to_arrow()` function but that looks like it only converts between different array types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be *YES* by using [`from_csv`](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.from_csv)/[`export_feather`](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.dataframe.DataFrameLocal.export_feather) as per the doc :

```
import vaex

vaex.from_csv("input.csv").export_feather("output.feather")
```